# Адаптивная картинка Css

Tags: css

у меня возникла проблема с адаптивном сайта. Прописываю свое фоновое изображение background-ом в header, мне нужно, чтобы оно сохранило свой размер и уменьшалось пропорционально размеру страницы, а выходит наоборот, когда страница сужается, оно теряет свой размер (скину фото). Я понимаю, что надо задавать фиксированную ширину, но мне надо на весь экран пользователя, не могу воспользоваться фиксацией.
код:

```
header {
    background-image: url('../img/thumb-1920-927560.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указывать `background-size: cover;`

```css
header {
    background-image: url('https://c.wallhere.com/photos/02/dd/2560x1600_px_landscape-792577.jpg!d');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```